# Floyd Warshall Algorithm for a planar grid graph

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph, shortest-path, floyd-warshall

I have a graph like this:

[image]

And I implemented graph array like this:

```
G[i][j][k]
```

`K`has only 4 cells and it shows whether the vertex is connected to its four neighbor vertices or not. For example for:

```
G[1][1][0] = 0 
G[1][1][1] = 1 
G[1][1][2] = 1 
G[1][1][3] = 0
```

It shows that the vertex(1, 1) is connected to 2 vertices.

I know the Floyd Warshall algorithm for normal types of graphs. **But how can I implement Flyod Warshall Algorithm for this kind of graph?**

Thank.

Comment: Why is this a different 'type' of graph. It's surely just an unweighted graph without multiple edges (a simple graph). There could even be simpler or faster algorithms than Floyd-Warshall for shortest path calculation. In fact, there definitely are - it's planar, for a start.

Comment: @gilleain is right. What's different is not the graph but rather the data structure used to represent the adjacency relations

Comment: @gilleain [This type of graph](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GridGraph.html) is called a [grid graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_graph), and they are often far easier handled than general graphs.

Comment: @G.Bach Are there algorithms for finding the shortest path that are faster for grid graphs than arbitrary planar graphs? It seems possible. Not sure it really matters having such a specific classification of the input graph, however.

Comment: @gilleain Seems unlikely asymptotically speaking, given that there's a linear-time algorithm for planar graphs that solves the same problem as Dijkstra's algorithm.

Comment: [Link to the algorithm David mentioned](http://theory.stanford.edu/~virgi/cs267/papers/planar-sssp.pdf), for the theoretically inclined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Floyd-Warshall algorithm would be very inefficient for such a sparse graph. The graph is sparse because every vertex connected to no more than 4 other vertices. In a dense graph a vertex can be connected to up to N-1 other vertices, where N is the number of vertices in the graph. That is where Floyd-Warshall algorithm would be more or less efficient, but still, if you don't need shortest paths between each pair of vertices or finding negative-length cycles, consider using priority queue for finding the shortest path between a source and all other vertices: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra's_algorithm#Using_a_priority_queue . Or even breadth first search can be used if the weights in your graph are equal for each edge (unweighted graph).

If you still want Floyd-Warshall algorithm for your grid, here it is. Consider the grid is `N` by `M`, with 1-based indexing so that the maximal entry in the grid is `G[N][M][...]`. Then Floyd-Warshall algorithm would be:

```
// edge offsets
const int offs[4][2] = {
    {-1, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}, {0, -1}
};
const int INF_DIST = 1e9;
int D[N+1][M+1][N+1][M+1];
//// Initialize weights to infinity
// For each source row and column (i,j)
for(int i=1; i<=N; i++) {
    for(int j=1; j<=M; j++) {
        // For each destination row and column (k,l)
        for(int k=1; k<=N; k++) {
            for(int l=1; l<=M; l++) {
                D[i][j][k][l] = INF_DIST;
            }
        }
    }
}
//// Mark edges of the graph
// For each row
for(int i=1; i<=N; i++) {
    // For each column
    for(int j=1; j<=M; j++) {
        // For each of the directions: up(k=0), right(k=1), down(k=2) and left(k=3)
        for(int k=0; k<=3; k++) {
            if(G[i][j][k] == 0) {
                // Don't add this edge to the distance matrix
                //   if the edge is not in the grid graph
                continue;
            }
            // Calculate (r, c) as the coordinates of the vertex one step 
            //   in the direction k
            int r = i + offs[k][0];
            int c = j + offs[k][1];
            if(1<=r && r <= N && 1<=c && c<=M) {
                // Only add the edge (if exists) in case (r, c) is within the grid
                D[i][j][r][c] = G[i][j][k];
            }
        }
    }
}
//// Find shortest paths between each pair of vertices
// For each intermediate vertex (k,l)
for(k=1; k<=N; k++) {
    for(l=1; l<=M; l++) {
        // For each source vertex (i,j)
        for(int i=1; i<=N; i++) {
            for(int j=1; j<=M; j++) {
                // For each destination vertex (r,c)
                for(int r=1; r<=N; r++) {
                    for(int c=1; c<=M; c++) {
                        // Apply the triangle rule
                        int alternative = D[i][j][k][l] + D[k][l][r][c];
                        if(alternative < D[i][j][r][c]) {
                            D[i][j][r][c] = alternative;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you explain the loops involved in ?why 4 loop in weight initialisation?for the graph i and j are row and column wat is k?can you explain a little bit

Comment: @user1234, I've added code comments. Please, let me know if something is not yet clear.

Comment: can you explain edge offset

Comment: Also int r = i + offs[k][0];
            int c = j + offs[k][1];
            if(1<=r && r <= N && 1<=c && c<=M) {
                D[i][j][r][c] = G[i][j][k];

Comment: @user1234, I've added comments there too.

Answer (score 3):

Your graph representation is basically an [adjacency list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list), for each vertex `v= G[i][j]`, you have a list containing the edges the graph is connected to. In your case, the list is made by 4 boolean values - each is indicating if the `(i,j)` is connected to `(i-1,j),(i+1,j),(i,j-1),(i,j+1)`, so using Floyd-Warshall algorithm with that understanding is pretty straight forward, if looking on the [wikipedia pseudo code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm#Algorithm):

```
1 let dist be a |V| × |V| array of minimum distances initialized to ∞ (infinity)
2 for each vertex v
3    dist[v][v] ← 0
4 for each edge (u,v)
5    dist[u][v] ← w(u,v)  // the weight of the edge (u,v)
6 for k from 1 to |V|
7    for i from 1 to |V|
8       for j from 1 to |V|
9          if dist[i][j] > dist[i][k] + dist[k][j] 
10             dist[i][j] ← dist[i][k] + dist[k][j]
11         end if
```

The main difference is in lines 4-5, where:

```
for each edge(u,v):
```

is actually

```
for each x=0,1,...,n-1
   for each y=0,1,...,m-1
       for each i=0,1,2,3:
             //if G[x][y][y] == 1 : it's an edge
```

---

Also note, in your graph, the maximum branch factor (number of edges connected to a node) is 4. This means, maximum number of edges in the graph is `|E| <= 4|V|`.

Since your graph is not directed, finding all-to-all shortest path can be done more efficiently by doing a [BFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) from each node, it will take `O(|V|*(|E|+|V|))` time, but since `|E| <= 4|V|`, this is `O(|V|^2)` - compared to Floyd-Warshall which runs in `O(|V|^3)`.